# Do React component gets re-rendered when global states defined by Redux changes?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am learning Redux using ReactJS and I have some doubts which I couldn't find elsewhere so I am asking here. As we know if we declare a state using useState hook and if that state gets changed then whole component gets re rendered. Is this also true for global states defined by Redux in React.

Answer (score 0):

Yes redux does re-render the component but it only re-renders those components which consume the state from the redux itself apart from your local useState hook